# Call process from process in Contiki

Tags: c, contiki, cooja, contiki-process

In my code, I need to declare two process. In the first process, I want to call the second one like this:

```
PROCESS_THREAD(Initialization_process, ev, data)
{    
  PROCESS_BEGIN();

   PROCESS_THREAD(example_broadcast_process, ev, data);

  PROCESS_END();
}
```

But I got this error:

```
error: invalid storage class for function ‘process_thread_example_broadcast_process’
```

How can we call a process from another process please?

Comment: Hello thank you I used process_start and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to start another process asynchronously, define this process (let's say `example_broadcast_process`) as usual, in the file scope, and then call [process_start()](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/processes) from the other process:

```
process_start(&example_broadcast_process, NULL);
```

If you desire synchronous operation, you can call `PT_SPAWN` to start a new protothread.